# Looping through a table twice

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to create a page that has a table. The table has a service and then the items under the service so the table should look like this

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed pricing_table">
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>
            Short
        </td>
        <td>
            Medium
        </td>
        <td>
            Long
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            Cut & Blow Dry
        </td>
        <td>
            R170
        </td>
        <td>
            R190
        </td>
        <td>
            R220
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            Blow Dry
        </td>
        <td>
            R120
        </td>
        <td>
            R170
        </td>
        <td>
            R190
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            Girls under 18
        </td>
        <td>
            R130
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            Pensioners
        </td>
        <td>
            R130
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            Gents Cut
        </td>
        <td>
            R120
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            Boys Cut
        </td>
        <td>
            R90
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            Upstyles - Trail
        </td>
        <td>
            R270
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            Upstyles
        </td>
        <td>
            R350
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

but what I'm getting is this

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed pricing_table">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td> Cutting & Styling </td>
            <td> Short </td>
            <td> Medium </td>
            <td> Long </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td> Cut & Blow Dry </td>
            <td> 150 </td>
            <td> 170 </td>
            <td> 190 </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td> Cutting & Styling </td>
            <td> Short </td>
            <td> Medium </td>
            <td> Long </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td> Blow Dry </td>
            <td> 100 </td>
            <td> 120 </td>
            <td> 140 </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td> Cutting & Styling </td>
            <td> Short </td>
            <td> Medium </td>
            <td> Long </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td> Girls under 18 </td>
            <td> 120 </td>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td> Cutting & Styling </td>
            <td> Short </td>
            <td> Medium </td>
            <td> Long </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td> Pensioners (Ladies) </td>
            <td> 70 </td>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td> Chemical Service </td>
            <td> Short </td>
            <td> Medium </td>
            <td> Long </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td> Color </td>
            <td> 150 </td>
            <td> 200 </td>
            <td> 250 </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td> Chemical Service </td>
            <td> Short </td>
            <td> Medium </td>
            <td> Long </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td> Half Head Foils </td>
            <td> 200 </td>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td> Chemical Service </td>
            <td> Short </td>
            <td> Medium </td>
            <td> Long </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td> Full Head Foils </td>
            <td> 300 </td>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td> Chemical Service </td>
            <td> Short </td>
            <td> Medium </td>
            <td> Long </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td> Per Foil </td>
            <td> 10 </td>
            <td> 15 </td>
            <td> 20 </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td> Chemical Service </td>
            <td> Short </td>
            <td> Medium </td>
            <td> Long </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td> Brazilian </td>
            <td> 700 </td>
            <td> 800 </td>
            <td> 900 </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td> Chemical Service </td>
            <td> Short </td>
            <td> Medium </td>
            <td> Long </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td> Perm </td>
            <td> 150 </td>
            <td> 170 </td>
            <td> 190 </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td> Treatment </td>
            <td> Short </td>
            <td> Medium </td>
            <td> Long </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td> Salon Treatment </td>
            <td> 100 </td>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td> Treatment </td>
            <td> Short </td>
            <td> Medium </td>
            <td> Long </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td> Olaplex - Stand Alon </td>
            <td> 180 </td>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The service is always being looped and displayed. I would only like the service to be looped once and the items to be displayed under their respective service.

My pricing.blade.php

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 about_content_area">
        <h1>pricing</h1>

        <div class="col-lg-5 col-lg-offset-3 col-md-5 col-md-offset-3 pricing_wrapper">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed pricing_table">
                @foreach($services_options as $services)
                    @foreach($services->service as $service)
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                {!! $service->title !!}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                Short
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                Medium
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                Long
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    @endforeach

                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                {!! $services->title !!}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                {!! $services->short !!}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                {!! $services->medium !!}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                {!! $services->long !!}
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                @endforeach
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My controller

```
public function content($id)
    {
        $menus_child = Menu::where('menu_id', 0)->with('menusP')->get();

        $menu = Menu::where('id', $id)->firstOrFail();

        $layout = $menu->type;

        $gallery_category = Gcategory::all();

        $services_options = Price::all();

        return view('open::public/'.$layout, compact('menus_child', 'menu', 'gallery_category', 'services_options'));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a loop for the header part of the table (the short, medium, long part) within the loop for each service, which is why its being output above each service row.

You just need to update `pricing.blade.php` to be the following

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 about_content_area">
        <h1>pricing</h1>

        <div class="col-lg-5 col-lg-offset-3 col-md-5 col-md-offset-3 pricing_wrapper">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed pricing_table">
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>
                        Short
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Medium
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Long
                    </td>
                </tr>
                @foreach($services_options as $services)
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            {!! $services->title !!}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {!! $services->short !!}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {!! $services->medium !!}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {!! $services->long !!}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```